# How to specify default values ​for Vue & Express & Mongo / mongoose's Date Type

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js

I am creating CRUD using VueJS, ExpressJS, and MongoDB.

I have a deadline: {Type: Date, optional: true} in Mongoose, but if I do not send a deadline value to Vue's input, I get an error in Express's Create API.

I want to generate a NULL if I do not specify a Date Value.

How can I do it?

**mongoose.js**

```
...
  deadline: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true
  },
```

**routes.js**

```
  let post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    deadline: req.body.deadline,
    // If there is no deadline value, "TypeError: Can not read property 'deadline' of undefined" occurs.
  });
```

**Vue Form Component**

```
    create: function() {
      if (!this.todo.deadline) {
        this.todo.deadline = ''
        // not working
      }
      this.$http.post('/api/posts/create', this.post)
      .then(
        (response) => {
        ...
      })
    }
```

Comment: in the component you should omit the `deadline` key from the object you send if it's blank. Even if you set it to optional in the model, the controller is still throwing an error because you're sending it the `deadline` key with no value.. aka your `req.body.deadline` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  let post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title?req.body.title:null,
    content: req.body.content?req.body.content:null,
    deadline: req.body.deadline?req.body.deadline:null,
  });
```

try this